# How to set YARN memoryOverhead from AWSCLI for EMR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr

I'm having a little trouble grokking why exactly my `Spark` job died, so I will include the traceback at the bottom of this post so that someone more experienced than me can give me some insight:)  As far as I can tell my nodes were dying because the memoryOverhead was being exceeded.  How can I set this from the `awscli` so that I don't run into this issue?

Here is some of my traceback:

```
16/05/17 20:20:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 97.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 9937, ip-172-31-14-59.us-west-2.compute.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 9 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.5 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 60.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 9900, ip-172-31-14-59.us-west-2.compute.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 9 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.5 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.5 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 134.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 9974, ip-172-31-14-59.us-west-2.compute.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 9 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.5 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 23.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 9863, ip-172-31-14-59.us-west-2.compute.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 9 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.5 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 9
16/05/17 20:20:46 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.5 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 15 on ip-172-31-14-46.us-west-2.compute.internal: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.5 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 88.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 9928, ip-172-31-14-46.us-west-2.compute.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 15 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.5 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 51.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 9891, ip-172-31-14-46.us-west-2.compute.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 15 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.5 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 125.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 9965, ip-172-31-14-46.us-west-2.compute.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 15 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.5 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 14.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 9854, ip-172-31-14-46.us-west-2.compute.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 15 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.5 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 15
16/05/17 20:20:46 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.6 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 14 on ip-172-31-14-61.us-west-2.compute.internal: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.6 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 85.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 9925, ip-172-31-14-61.us-west-2.compute.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 14 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.6 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 48.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 9888, ip-172-31-14-61.us-west-2.compute.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 14 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.6 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 122.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 9962, ip-172-31-14-61.us-west-2.compute.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 14 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.6 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/05/17 20:20:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 11.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 9851, ip-172-31-14-61.us-west-2.compute.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 14 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 5.6 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
1
```

Comment: How are you submitting your job to Amazon EMR? Passing `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` is a part of job submitting, not something you could change through `awscli`

Comment: spark - submit and a python file

Comment: @PawełJurczenko I also have ran it from the spark-shell.

Comment: Your full spark-submit command and the contents of the /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf file would probably help the diagnosis.

Comment: Also, it is actually possible to set spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead from the aws CLI. You would do so via the spark-defaults configuration classification, as described here: http://alpha-docs-aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html#spark-change-defaults (However, setting them at spark-submit time may still be more appropriate if you don't necessarily want this setting to apply to all Spark applications for the cluster.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply provide the configuration in the spark-submit command. For instance:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-client --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4096 --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 8G --executor-cores 6 ...
```

Comment: Thanks, and I assume this is something that would be passed in as a configuration setting if running the job from `boto3` or `awscli`?

Comment: Yes, via `awscli` you simply pass it in in your step definitions `--steps Name=MySparkJob,Type=Spark,Args=[--master,yarn-client,--conf,spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4096,...]` :-)

Comment: Is there a best practice for the over head you need vs the amount of RAM you job is set to use?

Comment: Well, I don't know of any best practices per se, but I personally find that if I need to assign more than 1/3 of my available memory to memoryOverhead, I have a general memory problem, and I need to re-think my code.